# How to update column value based on other column change within same table without any primary key column in table

Tags: postgresql, triggers, plpgsql, postgresql-9.3

I have a table called 'custom_manual_edit' with columns 'name', 'builder' and 'flag' in which there is no column with primary key.I have written a trigger when user update any change in builder column and that trigger will invoke a function that should update a flag column value to 10 for record for which builder value is changed
below is my trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER builder_update_trigger_manual_custom_edits
AFTER UPDATE
ON edmonton.custom_manual_edit
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (((old.builder)::text IS DISTINCT FROM (new.builder)::text))
EXECUTE PROCEDURE 
edmonton.automated_builder_update_trigger_manual_custom_edits();
```

and my function

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION 
edmonton.automated_builder_update_trigger_manual_custom_edits()
RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
e record;

BEGIN
IF NEW.builder <> OLD.builder THEN
    EXECUTE FORMAT('UPDATE edmonton.custom_manual_edit set builder_edit_flag = 10;
END IF;
RETURN NEW;

 END 
 $BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

I know this will update entire table flag column to 10 but how to update flag value for records for which builder value is changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check the documentation: [36.1. Overview of Trigger Behavior](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/trigger-definition.html)

> Trigger functions invoked by per-statement triggers should always
>   return NULL. Trigger functions invoked by per-row triggers can return
>   a table row (a value of type HeapTuple) to the calling executor, if
>   they choose. **A row-level trigger fired before an operation has the
>   following choices**:
>
> - It can return NULL to skip the operation for the current row. This
>     instructs the executor to not perform the row-level operation that
>     invoked the trigger (the insertion, modification, or deletion of a
>     particular table row).
> - For row-level INSERT and UPDATE triggers only, **the returned row
>     becomes the row that will be inserted or will replace the row being
>     updated. This allows the trigger function to modify the row being
>     inserted or updated.**
>
> A row-level BEFORE trigger that does not intend to cause either of
>   these behaviors must be careful to return as its result the same row
>   that was passed in (that is, the NEW row for INSERT and UPDATE
>   triggers, the OLD row for DELETE triggers).

According to the above you must:

1. declare the trigger as **BEFORE UPDATE**, not AFTER UPDATE
2. change`builder_edit_flag` column value **directly in NEW row** instead of firing UPDATE statement

---

```
CREATE TRIGGER builder_update_trigger_manual_custom_edits
BEFORE UPDATE
ON edmonton.custom_manual_edit
FOR EACH ROW
.....
.....
```

---

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION 
edmonton.automated_builder_update_trigger_manual_custom_edits()
.....
.....

BEGIN
IF NEW.builder <> OLD.builder THEN
    NEW.builder_edit_flag = 10;
END IF;
RETURN NEW;
.....
.....
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @krokodiiko